# How to add Text Field and Images in Navigation Bar of Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

I want to add text field and search icon on navigation bar of tab-bar controller. Please check attach image.

[image]

**Note**: This is home screen and if user click on any menu item it will goes to `detailvc` so i add one navigation controller on `homevc` and hide it.

I want to show *search icon* and *text-field* at navigation-bar of tabbar. how can i do this ?

Comment: This looks like android - do you mean android development?

Comment: You can take custom view instead of navigation bar with equal width and height. In this view you can set anything you want.

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney screenshort is from android but i want same in iOS.

Comment: @Jecky when embed tabbar the bar comes automatically.I can set title like this :- [self.tabBarController setTitle:@"Title"];
how can i add text-filed and imageview ?

Comment: @arpit you can create custom navigation bar.take a view and place textfield and image in view.

Answer (score 0):

set textfield with left view in **navigation title view**

navigationItem.titleView = UITextField()

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the navigationbar

`@interface SearchNavigationBar : UINavigationBar`

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
     UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchImage"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(searchPrompt:)];
     self.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
}
```

Add it as the class of your navigation controller

[image]

and get the object this way

`UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[SwitchAssessmentNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];`

and then you can call custom methods on the tool bar such as delegates that trigger events in your main page to change

Answer (score 0):

> searchBar in center of navigationBar:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBarTop;
```

> searchBar in left/right side of navigationBar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an UIView custom class which will hold your custom search bar.
Then add that view's instance into your navigationController's view.

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:yourCustomView];
```

Answer (score -1):

I have to add on own custom custom class of UItabbar-Contrller